# elasticbeanstalk python3.4 で numpy のインストールするときのコンパイルエラー

Tags: linux, aws, python3, gcc, numpy

elasticbeanstalk で numpy をインストールするとき、なんどもコンパイル失敗になりました。

64bit Amazon Linux 2017.03 v2.4.2 
running Python 3.4

助けてくださいー！

```
gcc: build/src.linux-x86_64-3.4/numpy/core/src/umath/loops.c
    Running from numpy source directory.
    /usr/lib64/python3.4/distutils/dist.py:260: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'python_requires'
      warnings.warn(msg)
    /usr/lib64/python3.4/distutils/dist.py:260: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'python_requires'
      warnings.warn(msg)
    /usr/lib64/python3.4/distutils/dist.py:260: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'define_macros'
      warnings.warn(msg)
    error: Command "gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -DDYNAMIC_ANNOTATIONS_ENABLED=1 -DNDEBUG -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -fPIC -DNPY_INTERNAL_BUILD=1 -DHAVE_NPY_CONFIG_H=1 -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE=1 -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE=1 -Ibuild/src.linux-x86_64-3.4/numpy/core/src/umath -Inumpy/core/include -Ibuild/src.linux-x86_64-3.4/numpy/core/include/numpy -Inumpy/core/src/private -Inumpy/core/src -Inumpy/core -Inumpy/core/src/npymath -Inumpy/core/src/multiarray -Inumpy/core/src/umath -Inumpy/core/src/npysort -I/usr/include/python3.4m -Ibuild/src.linux-x86_64-3.4/numpy/core/src/private -Ibuild/src.linux-x86_64-3.4/numpy/core/src/npymath -Ibuild/src.linux-x86_64-3.4/numpy/core/src/private -Ibuild/src.linux-x86_64-3.4/numpy/core/src/npymath -Ibuild/src.linux-x86_64-3.4/numpy/core/src/private -Ibuild/src.linux-x86_64-3.4/numpy/core/src/npymath -c build/src.linux-x86_64-3.4/numpy/core/src/umath/loops.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/build/src.linux-x86_64-3.4/numpy/core/src/umath/loops.o -MMD -MF build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/build/src.linux-x86_64-3.4/numpy/core/src/umath/loops.o.d" failed with exit status 4
    {standard input}: Assembler messages:
    {standard input}:1636168: Warning: end of file not at end of a line; newline inserted
    {standard input}:1636936: Error: can't resolve `.text' {.text section} - `.Ltex' {*UND* section}
    gcc: internal compiler error: Killed (program cc1)
    Please submit a full bug report,
    with preprocessed source if appropriate.
    See <http://bugzilla.redhat.com/bugzilla> for instructions.
    {standard input}: Assembler messages:
    {standard input}:1636168: Warning: end of file not at end of a line; newline inserted
    {standard input}:1636936: Error: can't resolve `.text' {.text section} - `.Ltex' {*UND* section}
    gcc: internal compiler error: Killed (program cc1)
    Please submit a full bug report,
    with preprocessed source if appropriate.
    See <http://bugzilla.redhat.com/bugzilla> for instructions.

    ----------------------------------------
Command "/opt/python/run/venv/bin/python3.4 -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-kf_ivae2/numpy/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-1e1ln3ou-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /opt/python/run/venv/include/site/python3.4/numpy" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-kf_ivae2/numpy
```

パッケージ：

```
packages:
  yum:
    git: []
    gcc: []
    mysql: []
    mysql-devel: []
    python34-devel: []
    atlas-devel: []
    lapack-devel: []
    blas-devel: []
```

requirements.txt

```
numpy
Django==1.10.1
django-cors-headers==1.2.2
djangorestframework==3.4.7
djangorestframework-jwt
requests
```

Comment: 出力を見るに、`/tmp/pip-1e1ln3ou-record/install-record.txt` のようなファイルにログが残っていそうに見えるのですが、そちらには何か有益な情報が残っていたりしませんか？

Comment: また、標準だと、pipのログが `~/.pip/pip.log` にあるかもしれません。

Comment: lxml や pandas のインストール時に似たようなエラーが出ている案件を見てみると、メモリ不足が原因のことがあるようです。スワップを一時的に増やす方法が使えるかもしれません。 https://stackoverflow.com/q/18334366/5989200

Comment: nekketsuuuさんありがとうございます。未解決のまま一旦デプロイ方法をDockerに変更して無事リリースできましたが、確かにメモリ不足とスワップ設定の可能性が大きいですね。再現してみます。